# How to use regex to rewrite a URI so the path becomes part of the query?

Tags: regex, uri

I have a problem which I would like to solve using a regex. I want a regex that will take the following input string and produce the following output;

```
input               output
-----               ------
/                   /?path=/
/mypath/            /?path=/mypath/
/?myquery           /?path=/&myquery
/mypath/?myquery    /?path=/mypath/&myquery
```

Can one regex do all of the above?

"No" is an acceptable answer. It would enable me to move on and look for an alternative solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll need regex for this. All it seems to be doing is replacing `?` with `&` and appending `/?path=` to the front.

Use a string `replace` function from your language of choice and tack on the `/?path=` to the beginning.

```
// Input: /mypath/?myquery
String myquery = "/mypath/?myquery";
myquery = myquery.replaceAll("?", "&");
myquery = "/?path=" + myquery;
// Output: /?path=/mypath/&myquery
```

Java's `replaceAll()` takes regex, but it's a literal so you don't *really* need to know any regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking specifically

> Can **one** regex do all of the above?

Googling it, I see that [perl can do multiple substitutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765894/can-i-substitute-multiple-items-in-a-single-regular-expression-in-vim-or-perl), but that doesn't seem like one regex. I'm going to say **no**, one regex cannot do multiple substitutions.

If you want to use only regex, it could look something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> uris = Arrays.asList("/", "/mypath/", "/?myquery", "/mypath/?myquery");
    for (String uri : uris)
        System.out.println(uri + "\n" + rewriteURI(uri) + "\n");
}

private static String rewriteURI(String uri) {
    return uri.replaceAll("\\?", "&").replaceAll("^", "/?path=");
}
```

Which produces

```
/
/?path=/

/mypath/
/?path=/mypath/

/?myquery
/?path=/&myquery

/mypath/?myquery
/?path=/mypath/&myquery
```

Comment: Maybe I've made the question unclear. I want one regex that will change '/' to '/?path=/' and '/mypath/' to '/?path=/mypath/' etc

Comment: Yeah, at first I thought you were dealing with a 4-line input. I pulled out the method I used so my function is more obvious. Does it bother you that it does two replacements? That's as close as you're going to get to "one regex" :)

Comment: I'm curious to know if regex alone can do this because if it can, then that's a portable solution. But currently I'm looking at "nginx" `http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule`.

Comment: If you want portable code, you are in luck, because either of the Java examples here should compile on **basically any machine.** Look how my regex replaceAll was able to do this: **regex alone can match your examples.** If this NGINX follows more obscure rules that need to happen, then either update your question or decide to use this other solution, but I doubt it is more portable than Java. If you do not want to be tied down to one programming language, you should know that how regex works is varied across languages... `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843256/how-to-make-portable-regex`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

Regex: `/^(\/[^?]*)(?:\?(.*))?/`
Replacement: `/?path=\1&\2`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. An input of `/ gives an output of `/?path=/&. I don't want the & at the end.

Comment: Can't you strip the trailing ampersand afterwards? PCRE doesn't support conditional insertion in the replacement string so if you really can't have the trailing ampersand this is not possible.